# Hana DB is not allowing nulls in a nullable field

Tags: sql, database, h2, hana

My shema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  newsletter_status(
    identificationnumber BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    bpid varchar(10),
    consumer varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    source varchar(10),
    vkorg varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    cryptid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(25),
    regDat timestamp,
    confirmDat timestamp,
    updateDat timestamp
  );

CREATE TABLE  scpnewsletter (version varchar(255));

CREATE INDEX bpid_index ON newsletter_status (bpid);
CREATE INDEX cryptid_index ON newsletter_status (cryptid);
```

Running locally in a H2-Database this works fine with insertions. Inserting a object which fields consumer,source,vkorg,cryptid and status ARE set, others dont. The Database should generate an identificationnumber. And the H2 does

When run on the customer DEV environment with a HANA DB the insertion fails, saying that:

```
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO newsletter_status (identificationnumber,bpid,consumer,source,vkorg,cryptid,status,regDat,confirmDat,updateDat) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [287]; SAP DBTech JDBC: [287]: cannot insert NULL or update to NULL: Not nullable &quot;IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER&quot; column; nested exception is com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [287]: cannot insert NULL or update to NULL: Not nullable &quot;IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER&quot; column
```

It does not likes that the Identificationnumber is null.

Going further. If I add an Identificationnumber it says the same thing about bpid:

```
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO newsletter_status (identificationnumber,bpid,consumer,source,vkorg,cryptid,status,regDat,confirmDat,updateDat) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [287]; SAP DBTech JDBC: [287]: cannot insert NULL or update to NULL: Not nullable &quot;BPID&quot; column; nested exception is com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [287]: cannot insert NULL or update to NULL: Not nullable &quot;BPID&quot; column
```

bpid can clearly be null in the shema. This ambiguity in consuming field confuses.

If both bpid and Identificationnumber are set, then the is not Problem with the database.

I want to store an object that both of this ids can be null, but also want an unique id for Identificationnumber.

I cant debug on the DEV env from the customer. Any Idea what possibly could go wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your `IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER` can never ever be NULL.

Based on the DDL provided, it has a NOT NULL constraint and is the single-column primary key, which implicitly makes it NOT NULL.

If H2 allows NULL inserts, that's an H2 bug/incompliant behavior.

Concerning the `BPID` column it looks like you're still trying to insert the value for `IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER` even though this value is defined as IDENTITY column. I assume, that by specifying NULL as a value for it, you want to make HANA use the DEFAULT value (the sequence).

If that's correct, then the answer is: it does not work this way.
Also: the error message wrongly named `BPID` as the problematic field.

The correct way to use DEFAULT values in INSERT statements in HANA is to leave the columns for which the DEFAULT values should be used, out from the column list.

SQL standard also has the option to use the `DEFAULT` keyword, but that's (currently, HANA 2 SPS 04) not supported.

Comment: The IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER is given from the Database itself. GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) give basica lly each new entry a new starting with 0, 1 ,2 ... etc. H2 works it out. Is it a wrong path to go?

Comment: HANA does the same thing with the identity field. The problem here seems to be - as explained in my answer - that your `INSERT` command lists the column as one of the columns to insert into. That does not work when you just omit binding an actual value to it. You have to remove the column from the insert command.

Comment: H2 *historically* allows not only the `DEFAULT`, but also the `NULL` to be specified as value for **identity** column; they both are converted to a generated value; that's why there is no error in H2, but normally you should use the `DEFAULT` anyway. (For non-identity columns `NULL` and `DEFAULT` are different things in H2.) Usually there is no need to list the identity column in the column list of an `INSERT` command and specify its value.